# Can I control .NET Core assembly redirects programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

**Question:** Is there any way in .NET Core 2.0 (netstandard 2.0) how I could apply assembly redirections NOT defined in given `application.exe.config` file when running executable? Maybe some programmatic way? Or even by running executable with some special settings/flags?

**Scenario:**
Here is simplified scenario that I'm trying to solve in .NET Core 2.0.

1. There is a "service hosting" executable, let's call it `ServiceHost.exe`
2. There is a service `.dll`, let's call it  `Service.dll`, which implements some entry interface `IService` with method `Start()`.
3. When I run `ServiceHost.exe --service-assembly Service.dll` it loads service and calls its `IService.Start()` implementation.
4. Author of the service can be anyone, it's independent on service host.

Let's say that the service needs some assembly redirects. It's quite common in .NET Core world when you reference much more packages than in old .NET Framework and not all of them have exact versions for latest .NET Core. Using assembly redirects works quite well and allows you to use library targeting older version just fine.

And here comes the problem with my setup. Since `Service.dll` is a library which is loaded by independent executable its `app.config` file with assembly redirects is not used. Runtime uses `ServiceHost.exe.config` and not `Service.dll.config`, which is expected.

**Reminder:** I'm using .NET Core so solution with creating new Application Domain and setting it to load different config file is not an option.

Comment: Create a new *process* and have it load a different config file, then. Either as a wrapper, or by re-invoking yourself with different parameters, after you've figured out what redirects the assembly to load wants. Basically, poor man's fork. (If you want to redirect standard input/output, that could get annoying.)

Comment: .NET Core doesn't have binding redirects and doesn't read any `.config` file, it just has some logic to scan for files in locations described by the `.deps.json` file, which is accessible via the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel` API. You could always load assemblies manually.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: If the process is still the same "servicehost.exe" it still loads the same "servicehost.exe.config". Only thing I can do is to change the content of that file before I start the new instance, which seems like not very good way.  

@MartinUllrich: .NET Core itself does not have binding redirects, that's true. In my case the .exe itself is .NET Core project targeting `net462` but all of the actual logic is in `netstandard2.0` library. So assembly redirects and `.config` are in play.

Comment: Target both .NET Core 2.0 and .NET 4.6.2, throw in some platform-specific code (`#if NET462 AppDomains`, `#if NETCOREAPP2_0 use dependency model`). Or just target .NET 4.6.2 exclusively if you're not actually planning on running your host on Linux. I am not suggesting you change the `.config` file for .NET Platform, I *was* suggesting you could change the file for whatever .NET Core uses (but apparently, it doesn't use files like that, so that's nice).

Comment: To come back to this from another angle: if the service "needs some assembly redirects", it wasn't designed with .NET Core in mind. A proper service would come with all of the binaries necessary to make that service run, with no dependency conflicts, using [`PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) logic. Your question may boil down to "how do I make assembly binding redirects possible for .NET Core", when the answer is "for .NET Core, you should probably find a way to live without them".

Comment: @JeroenMostert, you are right. My issue comes from fact that I need to target `net462` but I wanted to have code fully `netstandard2.0` compatible. That won;t work in my case due to need for assembly redirects in .NET 4.6.2. I solved it by leaving most of the libraries on `netstandard2.0` but having actual executable targeting `net462` and using Application Domains to load assembly redirects from config file. Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

We use a servicehost that is NetCore targeting NetFramework, you can use Automatic binding redirects:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This then generates the binding redirects automatically in the Servicehost.exe.config

Comment: It generates redirects when the application is built. My scenario is for runtime when .exe is already existing and needs to load arbitrary .dll.